# Why am I getting undefined index message

Tags: php, arrays, index-error

I've setup an array(simple), but when I try to echo back in table, I get the all-too-famous

> "Notice: Undefined index: xxxx in line...".

I've tried to change the syntax using different combinations of ' and ", also used ( instead of ['s.  None seem to work.

Document: example_1.php

```
  <?php $data = [
     ['nameID'=> '1','salutation'=> 'Mr','firstName'=> 
     'John','lastName'=> 'Smith'],
    ];
  ?>

    <table>
         <tr> 
            <td> <?php echo $data["nameID"]; ?> </td>
            <td> <?php echo $data["salutation"]; ?> </td>
            <td> <?php echo $data["firstName"]; ?> </td>
            <td> <?php echo $data["lastName"]; ?> </td>         
         </tr>      
    </table>
```

Just was trying to see if I could get the list items to show up in a table. There's no css setup or anything formating added to the code

---

Now for the next stage I was trying to setup an 'foreach' loop in order to extract other items added to array.  I've done a little research and I've found out that what I'm trying to do is extract from a nested array (without or with 
 list)
Here's my code:

```
<body>

  <table> 
    <?php foreach($data as $data) { ?>
    <tr> 
        <td> <?php echo $data["nameID"]; ?> </td>
        <td> <?php echo $data["salutation"]; ?> </td>
        <td> <?php echo $data["firstName"]; ?> </td>
        <td> <?php echo $data["lastName"]; ?> </td>         
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>


  </table>  

 </body>
```

Comment: You have an extra level of array (i.e. too many `[`) in `$data = [     ['nameID'=> '1` - `$data = ['nameID'=> '1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used `[` and `]` two times when declaring the array. Try this:

```
<?php 
    $data = ['nameID'=> '1','salutation'=> 'Mr','firstName'=> 'John','lastName'=> 'Smith']; 
?>

<table>
     <tr> 
        <td> <?php echo $data["nameID"]; ?> </td>
        <td> <?php echo $data["salutation"]; ?> </td>
        <td> <?php echo $data["firstName"]; ?> </td>
        <td> <?php echo $data["lastName"]; ?> </td>         
     </tr>      
</table>
```

Comment: I add this foreach to see if it would work
      <?php foreach($data as $data) { ?>
inserted into the table after table tag
      <?php } ?>
and this after the last </tr> b4 </table>

Comment: any ideas why I'm getting Illegal string offset. It's also returning the first letter of each variables data value

Comment: I have a slight difficulty in understanding exactly what you mean, is it possible you could add it to your question with the full code, or ask a new question with the link here?

Comment: Thanks for all your help.  I've added the steps I'm taking to increase my understanding of arrays.  Appreciate you...